# Is my graphics card suitable to run deep learning with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I would like to run deep learning functionality with MATLAB, and my graphics card needs to have compute capability 3.0 or higher. How do I find out whether it is supported? I checked my PC, and it says Intel HD graphics.

Does my PC support this functionality?

Comment: you can use a freeware [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/). Also, [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is a better to ask about PC setting/configuration etc. Your question has nothing to do with Matlab programming unless you are asking how to use Matlab to check GPU...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running MATLAB, you can type the command `gpuDevice` to return information about your graphics card, and it will tell you whether it's supported by MATLAB (i.e. compute capability 3.0 or higher). To run this you'll need to make sure you have a CUDA driver for your card installed (but if you run the command and you don't have the driver installed, MATLAB will give you an error message pointing you to the website where you can install the driver).

If it's a supported card, it should be capable of running MATLAB's deep learning functionality. Bear in mind that this functionality requires not only MATLAB, but also Parallel Computing Toolbox and Neural Network Toolbox as well.